# UDP internal routing issue when using multiple NIC's

Tags: linux, networking, routing, ethernet, udp

I have a server that has two ethernet ports, each one running on a separate NIC (eth0 and eth1).  I would like to connect eth0 to a separate machine that streams video over UDP (and no other traffic) while the other interface (eth1) is connected to the network gateway/router.

I don't care if the udp traffic port does not connect to the wider network.

Thank you!

EDIT: Since this question was put on hold, I would like to further clarify my system as per the comments below.  My system consists of a machine, running linux, with two ethernet NIC's.  I am receiving a UDP stream on one of those ports from a direct LAN-LAN connection to a security camera, and even though I've been able to read the packets coming in from the camera using `tcpdump` I have yet to be seeing anything coming through via `gstreamer` which I plan on using to display the video.

Both ports have a static IP address, configured as seen below:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 5C:F8:21:34:80:F6
      inet addr:192.168.1.233  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::5ef8:21ff:fe34:80f6%132688/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1237 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:90 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:113089 (110.4 KiB)  TX bytes:14016 (13.6 KiB)
      Interrupt:99

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 5C:F8:21:34:80:F7
      inet addr:192.168.1.234 Bcast:192.168.1.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1%132688/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:330 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:330 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
      RX bytes:277171 (270.6 KiB)  TX bytes:277171 (270.6 KiB)
```

And the internal routing table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth1
192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eth1
```

The camera is on address `192.168.1.239`, and broadcasts to my server directly over UDP. (the destination MAC is hardcoded into the packets)  It is broadcasting an MJPEG stream, and when I take the packets saved by `tcpdump` I can rebuild it into the MJPEG.

however, when I use `gstreamer` using the following command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc multicast-iface=eth0, port=1234 ! filesink location=foo
```

`foo` does not save any data.  I've used this machine to save udp streams using gstreamer in the past, but not when both ports were in use.  IE, the video was coming from another machine, through the router, to this server in question.

So, why can't these packets, which the server clearly sees and understands (it's not dropping them at least) not get to my gstreamer program?

Comment: What is the question?  When you connect `eth0` or `eth1` to the other machine, what do you expect to happen, and what do you observe that does not match your expectations?

Comment: The other server is streaming video over UDP, and when I connect eth0 to it directly, I would like to be able to receive that video stream using gstreamer

Comment: Good. So you can receive it. What's the problem?

Comment: The packets appear in tcpdump/wireshark, with correct MAC/IP, but do not go into my gstreamer application, even when I specify the interface in gstreamer.  So I figure that it's an internal routing issue.

Comment: Some details via `ifconfig` or `netstat` might be handy.

Comment: I've edited the question to be more clear, with ifconfig/netstat -nr results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you'd assign your cross-connect its own /30 subnet, from another bit of RFC1918 (private) space. So you'd do something like this:

- 192.168.1.234/24 is your LAN on eth1
- 192.168.255.1/30 is this machine, on eth0 (the cross-connect)
- 192.168.255.2/30 is the video source, on its end of the cross-connect

If you then 192.168.255.1 and 192.168.255.2 as the IP addresses for your UDP connection, it'll flow over eth0.

It is possible to do this using the same subnet as the LAN (using /32 routes, policy routing, or bridge tricks), but all of those are more complicated and more likely to have issues with confusing random programs.

(Quick explanation of /x notation: It's a short way of specifying the netmask, by counting the number of 1s [binary!] from the left/most significant bit. So /30 means a netmask of 255.255.255.252.)

Comment: Looks like that did it, along with having to use `ifconfig eth0 up` at boot since `auto` and `allow-hotplug` didn't appear to start the eth0 interface at boot when it starts receiving the UDP stream.  But that's a question for another day.

Comment: @T.Wallis Glad to hear the answer worked. BTW: `auto eth0` or `allow-hotplug eth0` should definitely work in `/etc/network/interfaces`, that indeed does sound like a good question if it's not. At least, presuming it wasn't just a typo.